# Error: Maximum update depth exceeded (again!)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-hooks, react-toolbox

I'm guessing that this is React 101 and has been asked a stack of times, but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Something is causing this code to get into an endless render loop and crash. I suspected the isLoggedIn flag, but am not so sure now. x.loginSlice.isLoggedIn is a straight boolean which is being set in reducer created by redux-toolkits createSlice helper. I assume that it's not violating any of the 'don't mutate state' rules.

My assumption is that this should only re-render when the equality check function on useSelector detects a change in the redux store. Perhaps something else is doing it? Location perhaps? It's still eluding me as to exactly how location is being passed in 'magically' via react-router.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you :-)

```
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<{ path: string, exact: boolean, children: ReactNode }> = ({children, ...rest}) => {

    const isLoggedIn = useSelector((x: RootState) => x.loginSlice.isLoggedIn, (x, y) => x===y)
    console.log('rendering privateRoute')

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={({location}) =>
                isLoggedIn ? (
                    children
                ) : (
                    <Redirect
                        to={{
                            pathname: "/page/Login",
                            state: {from: location}
                        }}
                    />
                )
            }
        />
    );
}

const App: React.FC = () => {
        core.RunSetup()
        const darkMode = useAppSelector(x => x.settings.darkMode)
        return (
            <IonApp className={darkMode === 'dark' ? 'dark-theme' : ''}>
                <IonReactRouter>
                    <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
                        <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
                            <Route path="/" exact={true}>
                                <Redirect to="/page/Login"/>
                            </Route>

                            <Route path="/page/:name" exact={true}>
                                <Page/>
                            </Route>

                            <PrivateRoute path="/study/Counter" exact={true}>
                                <LearningPageWrapper page={TestPages.counter}/>
                            </PrivateRoute>

                        </IonRouterOutlet>

                        <Menu/>
                    </IonSplitPane>;
                </IonReactRouter>
            </IonApp>
        );
    }
;

export default App;
```

*Additional Resources*

After reading some comments I've deeper into the other pages which are getting rendered.

According to react profiler:

- 'Router' seems to be the highest level component which is participating in the ongoing render loop
- "why did this render" for the Router is "State Changed:Location". I'm looking into the router docs more around this.

I've shared some files [here](https://github.com/damiensawyer/Troubleshooting-React-Endless-Loop) if it's of any help. Included are the console log during the crash, the exported react profiler data and all the tsx files. I've hacked around with the later to try and make them as minimalistic as possible.

Thanks again for your help! Despite the hair loss I get the feeling I'm learning something important here.

### Edit 2: It seems to be working, but I'm not sure why.

If I remove `state: {from: location}` the problem seems to go away. I'm not sure why, but notice that this privateRoute is still rendering even when navigating to `page/login` which is supposed to be just a normal route.
I'm wondering if [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/match/null-matches) might be the resason. Perhaps the changing pathName in the location object is changing the props passed to `PrivateRoute` and causing it to go into an endless loop.

Anyway - for now I'm unstuck. I'll leave the question open in case anyone wants to explain it all to me.

Comment: i think `core.RunSetup()` should trigger only on component load. It should be inside useEffect

Comment: Thanks @SarunUK. I didn't even see that there. I pulled it out and It's not the culprit though.

Comment: code of `Page` component?

Comment: @DamienSawyer Can you provide a screenshot of the complete error in the console? It should say something like `at BrokenComponent` right under the `index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded.` warning. That would at least give us an indication what component is causing this instead of guessing what is causing it.

Comment: Thanks @HMR. I looked through the logs and couldn't see anything like `BrokenComponent`. I've put more logging in though and run it all through the profiler and am now thinking the change in state for Location is suspicious. I've added more information above. Thanks again!